# How to enter a filepath as a flag in CLI and how to read the file contents?

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I want to enter a file path as a flag in my command line interface which I coded in Go. My ultimate goal is to read the content of that file whose path I enter as a flag. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
    app := &cli.App{
    Flags: []cli.Flag{
        &cli.StringFlag{
            Name:        "privatekeypath",
            Value:       "no value",
            Aliases:     []string{"y"},
            Usage:       "random",
            Destination: &priv_path,
        },
        &cli.StringFlag{
            Name:        "privatekey",
            Value:       "no value",
            Aliases:     []string{"k"},
            Usage:       "random",
            Destination: &userprivatekey,
            FilePath:    priv_path,
        },
```

The above code reads the value of the path in the variable priv_path and the actual content in userprivatekey. The command line was as follows:

randomcli --privatekeypath=/abc/def/privatekey.txt

Comment: What is cli and what  dod not work?

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using library `github.com/urfave/cli`, if so, you can get the value by name or aliases.

```
c.String("privatekey")
```

or

```
c.String("k")
```